# Mutiple sums from a collection in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

How can I find sum of two fields from a collection in Kotlin?

```
val students = listOf(
    Student("x", 10, 20),
    Student("y", 20, 40),
    Student("z", 30, 60)
)
val totalAge = students.sumOf { it.age }
val totalScore = students.sumOf { it.score }
```

Is there a way to achieve above totals in one go, to avoid two iterations?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid two iterations? If it's for performance, then I think it would only be worth doing something more complex (e.g. as Sweeper's answer shows) after demonstrating that a) this code was a significant performance bottleneck, and b) the alternative performed significantly better. IME, neither of those are likely to be true. (For the latter, note that modern JVMs do a lot of optimisation.) In general, it's usually far better to write clear, simple, straightforward code (like that above) and worry about optimisation later.

Comment: (Remember [Michael A. Jackson’s Rules Of Optimisation](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Michael_A._Jackson#Principles_of_program_design,_1975): Rule 1. Don’t do it. Rule 2 (for experts only). Don’t do it yet — that is, not until you have a perfectly clear and unoptimised solution.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fold` and fold it into a `Pair<Int, Int>`.

```
val (totalAge, totalScore) = students.fold(0 to 0) { (age, score), student ->
    age + student.age to score + student.score
}
```

But honestly I think just a simple `for` loop is more readable (and avoids creating all those `Pair`s too).

```
var totalAge = 0
var totalScore = 0
for (student in students) {
    totalAge += student.age
    totalScore += student.score
}
```

If `Student` is a data class,

```
data class Student(val name: String, val age: Int, val score: Int)
```

you could make it a little shorter by destructuring

```
for ((_, age, score) in students) {
    totalAge += age
    totalScore += score
}
```